# Externally provided HTML for an ng-bootstrap popover

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

The Angular version of a Bootstrap Popover component is described at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples .  The example used for using using HTML in the popover is:

```
<ng-template #popContent>Hello, <b>{{name}}</b>!</ng-template>
```

This is fine if you are specifying the HTML formatting in the HTML, but doesn't work if you are providing the HTML from a TypeScript method, for example to import it from a server:

```
<ng-template #popContent>{{getMyHtmlFromTheServer()}}</ng-template>
```

The HTML code shows up in the popover.  It would be good if the documentation gave such an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Comment: My comment was primarily aimed at enhancing the ng-bootstrap documentation with information that is non-obvious from that documentation and is a very common use case.

Answer (score 2):

The following code allows you to use HTML code provided by a TypeScript method:

```
<ng-template #popContent><div [innerHTML]="getMyHtmlFromTheServer()"></div></ng-template>
```